# google action simulator not display correct response

Tags: actions-on-google

When i test my smart home action with Simulator, the action is working and response correctly (work fine when test with Google Assistance app) but the Simulator show error.

```
{
    "response": "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.",
    "expectUserResponse": false,
    "conversationToken": "Eo8CS2s1Wm...",
    "ssmlMarkList": [],
    "visualResponse": {
      "visualElementsList": [
        {
          "displayText": {
            "content": "Sure, turning the abc on."
          }
        }
      ],
      "suggestionsList": [],
      "agentLogoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/voice/opa/partner_icons/generic_3p_avatar.png",
      "agentStyle": {
        "primaryColor": "",
        "fontFamily": "",
        "borderRadius": 0,
        "backgroundColor": "",
        "backgroundImageUrl": ""
      }
    },
    "clientError": 8,
    "is3pResponse": false,
    "clientOperationList": [],
    "projectName": ""
  }
```

Actually the correct response is "Sure, turning the abc on." (as display by Assistance app) but don't know why the Simulator treat it as "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again." error.

Comment: Hello @huy phamquoc, Could you please share more info on, what are you trying to do, and share the info on your basic research you have done to resolve the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a smart home action?

Comment: yes, this is a smart home action. I follow this guild https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create. I just test with 1 switch device. It work well with Google Home app (account linking, query, command, ...) but had problem with the Simulator (noticed that my action is not deployed).

Comment: The expect result is in [visualResponse.visualElementsList.displayText.content]. I just don't know why the Simulator not display it.

Comment: Hello @huy, did you resolve this?  I am also having the same issue.  The action works fine with google home app, but it is always displaying this error.  I wonder what ClientError:8 really means.  I couldn't find any info about this error code.